# Suppressing verbose ansicolor command to jenkins console output

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have defined a helper file for my logging purposes as such:

> **logger.groovy**
>
> ```
> import groovy.transform.Field
>
> @Field color = [
>   reset   : "\033[0m",
>   red     : "\033[31m",
>   green   : "\033[32m",
>   yellow  : "\033[33m",
>   blue    : "\033[34m",
>   magenta : "\033[35m",
>   cyan    : "\033[36m"
> ]
>
> def info(String str)
> {
>   ansiColor()
>   {
>     println("${color.green}${str}")
>   }
> }
> ```

I am then using it in my main build file as such:

```
logger.info("Logging at info level")
logger.info("another log message")
```

Doing so correctly shows my text as green (can't mimic here), but it's also printing a lot of junk:

> **Output:**
>
> ```
> [Pipeline] ansiColor
> [Pipeline] {
> [Pipeline] echo
> Logging at info level
> [Pipeline] }
> [Pipeline] // ansiColor
> [Pipeline] ansiColor
> [Pipeline] {
> [Pipeline] echo
> another log message
> [Pipeline] }
> [Pipeline] // ansiColor
> ```

How can I get it to disable all the extraneous source lines? I would like to keep that feature enabled in my main script, I just really don't need it every time I want to log something.

I have tried putting in the shebangs at the top of the logger.groovy file, but to no avail. I also have my jenkins instance running on Windows, which might help explain why. I have also tried putting `set +x` in the info() method, but that only results in the following exception, which is likely due to the sandbox environment

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: set for class: logger
```

I'm not sure why I'm having such a hard time with this. Do other people just deal with it or am I doing something out of the ordinary?

Comment: Sounds like https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-45210

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/jenkinsci/ansicolor-plugin#using-in-pipeline-workflows

TERM is a variable that's set to the color mapping when the ansiColor block is in scope. If TERM is not null, we're already inside an ansiColor block so we don't need to re-add it.

So here is my work around for the ansicolor logging:

```
def info(String str) {
  if (env.TERM) {
    println("${color.green}${str}")
  } else {
    ansiColor {
      println("${color.green}${str}")
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know if it's possible to get rid of the logging of "echo"